# How to use Base64 in PHP to post an image?

Tags: php, curl, base64

I need to use a `Base64` encoded `.jpg` image because I can't use a hosted image.
How to use the $base64image for the `submitted-image-url` array part?

PHP:

```
$base64image ="AAABAAEAEBAAAAEAIABoBAAAFgAAACgAAAAQAAAAIAAAAAEAIAAAAAAAAAAAABMLAAATCwAAAAAA
    AAAAAAAAAAAAbGxt/==";

$postData = array(
 'visibility' => array('code' => 'anyone'),
 'content' => array('submitted-url' => "http://example.com",'title' =>"helloworld",  'submitted-image-url' => "http://www.example.com/mypic.png"),
);

$ch = curl_init('https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?oauth2_access_token='.$authToken );
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
     'Content-Type: application/json'
    ),
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($postData)
));
```

Thank you

Comment: that'd depend on linkedin and if they allow data uris for such things. If they expect a full-blown url from which THEY fetch the image, then you're out of luck.

Comment: @MarcB I would like to try it out. Can you please show me an example how to use the data uris/Base64?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. You must have to provide a hosted image link to the linked in api. They will use your image's link with the share.

You can host a PHP script on your server. send your base64 encoded image to the script and make the script to return image from the base64. Use gd library of PHP for this. Example:

```
yourserver/img/getImg.php?image=AAABAAEAE...
```

Still, it may not work. Cause it will make your image link too large, and I am afraid linkedin may not accept such a large image url as parameter. You can try to shorten the image's link from your server, but thats a different story.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I need to work with other API's where Base64 is possible. Can you please show me an example how to use Base64 in PHP/cURL?

Comment: CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => base64_encode(file_get_contents($img_file))

Comment: The image is already encoded such like this: `$base64image ="AAABAAEAEBAAAAEAIABoBAAAFgAAACgAAAAQAAAAIAAAAAEAIAAAAAAAAAAAABMLAAATCwAAAAAA
    AAAAAAAAAAAAbGxt/==";` How to send that? Is it something like this `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => base64($base64image)`?

Comment: if you have already encoded image, then pass it directly. CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $base64image; Also, make sure to check the 'content-type' header from their API doc. You may need to use image/jpeg for this.